# libtcod root is messing up

Tags: c++, libtcod

Everytime I run this the window closes immediatly, and returns 3

```
#include "libtcod.hpp"

int main() {
    TCODConsole::initRoot(80,50, "j", false);
    while ( !TCODConsole::isWindowClosed() ) {
        TCODSystem::checkForEvent(TCOD_EVENT_KEY_PRESS,NULL,NULL);
        TCODConsole::root->clear();
        TCODConsole::root->putChar(40,25,'@');
        TCODConsole::flush();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try running your program in a debugger, to see which function is it that exits the process.

Comment: It is the root->clear function. And if I take that out it is the root->putChar function that messes up

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong with the code itself.  You'll want to check that your linker is set up properly.

Additionally, see here:

http://codeumbra.eu/complete-roguelike-tutorial-using-c-and-libtcod-part-1-setting-up

For an explanation and brief tutorial.